# Scala: How do I dynamically instantiate an object and invoke a method using reflection?

Tags: reflection, scala, name-mangling

In Scala, what's the best way to dynamically instantiate an object and invoke a method using reflection?

I would like to do Scala-equivalent of the following Java code:

```
Class class = Class.forName("Foo");
Object foo = class.newInstance();
Method method = class.getMethod("hello", null);
method.invoke(foo, null);
```

In the above code, both the class name and the method name are passed in dynamically. The above Java mechanism could probably be used for `Foo` and `hello()`, but the Scala types don't match one-to-one with that of Java. For example, a class may be declared implicitly for a singleton object. Also Scala method allows all sorts of symbols to be its name. Both are resolved by name mangling. See [Interop Between Java and Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala).

Another issue seems to be the matching of parameters by resolving overloads and autoboxing, described in [Reflection from Scala - Heaven and Hell](http://www.familie-kneissl.org/Members/martin/blog/reflection-from-scala-heaven-and-hell).

Comment: Given that the experimental feature in my answer did not make 2.8.0, it would be better if another answer was marked as accepted.

Comment: if i have class with parameters for a class like 
    class MailServerice(emailIds : string)
is it possible to invoke dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There is an easier way to invoke method reflectively without resorting to calling Java reflection methods: use Structural Typing.

Just cast the object reference to a Structural Type which has the necessary method signature then call the method: no reflection necessary (of course, Scala is doing reflection underneath but we don't need to do it).

```
class Foo {
  def hello(name: String): String = "Hello there, %s".format(name)
}

object FooMain {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val foo  = Class.forName("Foo").newInstance.asInstanceOf[{ def hello(name: String): String }]
    println(foo.hello("Walter")) // prints "Hello there, Walter"
  }
}
```

Comment: Structural Type won't help me if I don't know the method name at the compile time.

Comment: using a type alias to give the structural type a name often improves the readability of this trick.

Comment: This only answers part of the question. Is there a Scala centric way of performing Method method = class.getMethod("hello", null);?

Comment: In this example Foo takes no constructor parameters, but if there were, how would you go about passing them in on `newInstance`?

Comment: What if we don't know the method names? Just that the class is actually an `object`. Why? Its a long story. In a nutshell, I need the user to input a object/class and then I want to find all methods in that object/class.

Comment: Executing this in scala repl I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Foo (wrong name: Foo)`

Comment: Say your type is Array[Int], it means that you must use `Class.forName("[I")`, how do you get `"[I"` from `"Array[Int]"` that you can get from a TypeTag?

Comment: What if we have another function bye() inside class foo and i want to call that too. how do i add that in instance of?

Answer (score 12):

The answers by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) and [Walter Chang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144628/walter-chang) are quite good, so I'll just complement with one Scala 2.8 Experimental feature. In fact, I won't even bother to dress it up, I'll just copy the scaladoc.

```
object Invocation
  extends AnyRef
```

> A more convenient syntax for reflective
>   invocation. Example usage:

```
class Obj { private def foo(x: Int, y: String): Long = x + y.length }
```

> You can call it reflectively one of
>   two ways:

```
import scala.reflect.Invocation._
(new Obj) o 'foo(5, "abc")                 // the 'o' method returns Any
val x: Long = (new Obj) oo 'foo(5, "abc")  // the 'oo' method casts to expected type.
```

> If you call the oo
>   method and do not give the type
>   inferencer enough help, it will most
>   likely infer Nothing, which will
>   result in a ClassCastException.
>
> Author Paul Phillips

Comment: This is kind of what I had in mind from the linked blog article. Another piece of the puzzle is the name mangling service.

Comment: Sadly, Invocation didn't end up making it:
https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/19695

Answer (score 7):

The instanciation part *could* use the [**Manifest**](http://scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html): see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818996/abstract-types-type-parameters-in-scala/820345#820345)

> experimental feature in Scala called manifests which are a way to get around a Java constraint regarding type erasure

```
 class Test[T](implicit m : Manifest[T]) {
   val testVal = m.erasure.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]
 }
```

> With this version you still write

```
class Foo
val t = new Test[Foo]
```

> However, if there's no no-arg constructor available you get a runtime exception instead of a static type error

```
scala> new Test[Set[String]] 
java.lang.InstantiationException: scala.collection.immutable.Set
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
```

So the true type safe solution would be using a Factory.

---

Note: as stated in [this thread](http://www.nabble.com/Manifest-question-td24108792.html), Manifest is here to stay, but is for now "only use is to give access to the erasure of the type as a Class instance."

> The only thing manifests give you now is the erasure of the *static* type of a parameter at the call site (contrary to `getClass` which give you the erasure of the *dynamic* type).

---

You can then get a method through reflection:

```
classOf[ClassName].getMethod("main", classOf[Array[String]])
```

and invoke it

```
scala> class A {
     | def foo_=(foo: Boolean) = "bar"
     | }
defined class A

scala>val a = new A
a: A = A@1f854bd

scala>a.getClass.getMethod(decode("foo_="),
classOf[Boolean]).invoke(a, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE)
res15: java.lang.Object = bar
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you need to invoke a method of a Scala 2.10 object (not class) and you have the names of the method and object as `String`s, you can do it like this:

```
package com.example.mytest

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

class MyTest

object MyTest {

  def target(i: Int) = println(i)

  def invoker(objectName: String, methodName: String, arg: Any) = {
    val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val moduleSymbol = runtimeMirror.moduleSymbol(
      Class.forName(objectName))

    val targetMethod = moduleSymbol.typeSignature
      .members
      .filter(x => x.isMethod && x.name.toString == methodName)
      .head
      .asMethod

    runtimeMirror.reflect(runtimeMirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol).instance)
      .reflectMethod(targetMethod)(arg)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    invoker("com.example.mytest.MyTest$", "target", 5)
  }
}
```

This prints `5` to standard output.
Further details in [Scala Documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html).

Comment: What about a class, not an object?

Answer (score 5):

Working up from @nedim's answer, here is a *basis* for a full answer, 
main difference being here below we instantiate naive classes. This code does not handle the case of multiple constructors, and is by no means a full answer.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

case class Case(foo: Int) {
  println("Case Case Instantiated")
}

class Class {
  println("Class Instantiated")
}

object Inst {

  def apply(className: String, arg: Any) = {
    val runtimeMirror: universe.Mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

    val classSymbol: universe.ClassSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(Class.forName(className))

    val classMirror: universe.ClassMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)

    if (classSymbol.companion.toString() == "<none>") // TODO: use nicer method "hiding" in the api?
    {
      println(s"Info: $className has no companion object")
      val constructors = classSymbol.typeSignature.members.filter(_.isConstructor).toList
      if (constructors.length > 1) { 
        println(s"Info: $className has several constructors")
      } 
      else {
        val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructors.head.asMethod) // we can reuse it
        constructorMirror()
      }

    }
    else
    {
      val companionSymbol = classSymbol.companion
      println(s"Info: $className has companion object $companionSymbol")
      // TBD
    }

  }
}

object app extends App {
  val c = Inst("Class", "")
  val cc = Inst("Case", "")
}
```

Here is a `build.sbt` that would compile it:

```
lazy val reflection = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value % "provided",
      "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value % "provided"
    )
  )
```

Comment: related followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227984/perfectly-handling-scala-constructors-in-dynamic-instantiation