# Is there any way to set a default value to generic type variable in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to set a default value to variable. But my Scala compiler says:

```
Error:(20, 16) unbound placeholder parameter
    val p: T = _
               ^
```

Here is the code.

```
object InverseFunctionsExample extends App {

  type D = Double

  def f(x: D): D = 5 * x + 10
  def g(x: D): D = 0.2 * x - 2

  printMessage(isInversible(f, g))

  def printMessage(inv: Boolean): Unit = {
    if (inv) print("YES!") else print("NOPE!")
  }

  def isInversible[T](f: (T) => T, g: (T) => T): Boolean = {
    val p: T = _
    if (f(p) == g(p))
      true
    else
      false
  }
}
```

Is it possible to initialize a `val p` with default value somehow?

Comment: If you know nothing about a type, how would you get a default value from it.

Comment: What would T be? You'd probably need a constraint of being Defaultable on T, and implement such a Trait. This is hard for the same reason why you can't initialize an instance of T, then use it in a class.

Comment: Just an observation here. You've defined f as the inverse of g. But your test doesn't check for this, you'd want `f(g(p)) == p` and for all p, not just a single value.

Answer (score 3):

Only `var` fields (not local variables) can be initialized in this way. If you want to define "default values" for different types, the standard approach is [the type-class pattern](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html):

```
case class Default[T](value: T)

object Default {
  implicit val defaultInt: Default[Int] = Default(0)
  implicit val defaultString: Default[String] = Default("")
  ...
}

def isInversible[T](f: (T) => T, g: (T) => T)(implicit d: Default[T]): Boolean = {
  if (f(d.value) == g(d.value))
    true
  else
    false
  // or just f(d.value) == g(d.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to instantiate a new instance of a class, but that's probably not going to be very useful for you here:

```
class Foo
classOf[Foo].getConstructor().newInstance()
```

You can read about the reflection API to see you how you can pick a suitable constructor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641104/instantiate-object-with-reflection-using-constructor-arguments).

You could also have a parameter that specifies how to instantiate a new instance:

```
def isInversible[T](f: T => T, g: T => T, def: => T) = f(def) == g(def)
```

Since this looks like an inherently math-oriented problem, you might be interested in the `Numeric` type, which can help facilitate this kind of logic generically for different number types.  For example:

```
def intersectAtOrigin[T](f: T => T, g: T => T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
    val zero = n.zero
    f(zero) == g(zero)
}
```

And then you can do:

```
def f(x: D): D = 5 * x + 10
def g(x: D): D = 0.2 * x - 2
intersectAtOrigin(f, g) //false, working with Doubles
intersectAtOrigin[Int](_ + 1, x => x * x + x + 1) //true, working with Ints
```

You can read more about `Numeric` in the docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.math.Numeric).

Comment: just a small note: `Numeric` comes with a [`zero` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L205), so you don't need to do `fromInt(0)`; `n.zero` will suffice.

Comment: @dhg Great.  Thanks for the note, I've updated the answer to include use of `zero`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in the value as a parameter of type T

```
def isInversible[T](f: (T) => T, g: (T) => T)(p: T): Boolean = {

    if (f(p) == g(p))
      true
    else
      false
  }
```

An example  **printMessage(isInversible(f, g)(10))**