# Dynamically access methods from scala object

Tags: scala, dynamic, reflection

In Scala, what's the best way to dynamically call an object and invoke a method using reflection? The method corresponding to the object is to be called but the object name is known dynamically.

I was able to instantiate a scala class dynamically from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469958/scala-how-do-i-dynamically-instantiate-an-object-and-invoke-a-method-using-refl) however I need to do the same thing for an object.

Here is a sample code for some clarity:

```
class CC {
   def CC () = {
   }
}
object CC {
    def getC(name : String) : CC = {
        return new CC();
        }
    }
}
class CD {
   def CD () = {
   }
}
object CD {
   def getC(name : String) : CC = {
        return new CD();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I've a base class, which needs to call the `getC` method but the corresponding object is know dynamically. So how does one achieve the same?

Also the base class and my doubt is in the comments of the class.

```
class Base {
   def Base() = {
   }
   def createClass(name : String) = {
     // need to call the method corresponding to the object depending
     // on the string. 
     //e.g.: if name = "C" call CC.getC("abcd")
     //      if name = "D" call CD.getC("abcd")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could still use scala runtime reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val ccr = m.staticModule("my.package.name.ObjName") // e.g. "CC" or "CD"
type GetC = {
 def getC(name:String): CC
} 
val cco = m.reflectModule(ccr).instance.asInstanceOf[GetC]
```

now you could use it as `cco.getC ...`