# Perfectly handling scala constructors in dynamic instantiation

Tags: scala

I have put together this working code that dynamically instantiates a class from a given `name: String` (below). This works for the easy case - classes and case classes that have one constructor.

I am not sure how to handle the general case where several constructors exist. I assume they can only be differentiated by their signatures, but find the conceptual interaction between companion objects, classes and case classes a bit confusing to reason about. What would be a full description of all "construction" scenarios that need to be accounted for, or, how would you evolve this to become fully generic?

Demonstrating its inflexibility, this code embarrassingly fails at going through the companion object.

Hopefully this code affords convenient test & tinker flows, if someone cares joining on this thought drill.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

case class CaseClass(foo: Int) {
  println(s"${getClass.getSimpleName} Instantiated with $foo")
}

class BaseClass(foo: Int) {
  println(s"${getClass.getSimpleName} Instantiated with $foo")
}

object BaseClass { 
  def apply(foo:Int) = {
    println(s"going through companion object ${getClass.getSimpleName}")
    new BaseClass(foo+10) }
  }

class GenericClass[T](foo: T) {
  println(s"${getClass.getSimpleName} Instantiated with $foo")
}

object Inst {

  private def log(s: String) = println(Console.YELLOW + Console.BOLD + s + Console.RESET)

  private def selectConstructor(symbol: universe.Symbol) = {
    val constructors = symbol.typeSignature.members.filter(_.isConstructor).toList
    if (constructors.length > 1) log(
           s"""Warning: $symbol has several constructors, arbitrarily picking the first one: 
              |         ${constructors.mkString("\n         ")}""".stripMargin)
    constructors.head.asMethod
  }

  def apply(className: String, arg: Any) = {
    val runtimeMirror: universe.Mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

    val classSymbol: universe.ClassSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(Class.forName(className))

    val classMirror: universe.ClassMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)

    if (classSymbol.companion.toString() == "<none>") // TODO: use nicer method "hiding" in the api?
    {
      log(s"Info: $className has no companion object")
      val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(selectConstructor(classSymbol)) // we can reuse it
      constructorMirror(arg)
    }
    else
    {
      val companionSymbol = classSymbol.companion
      log(s"Info: $className has companion object $companionSymbol")
      val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(selectConstructor(classSymbol)) // we can reuse it
      constructorMirror(arg)
    }   
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val c1 = Inst("BaseClass", 3)
  val c2 = Inst("BaseClass", 4)
  val cc = Inst("CaseClass", 5)
  val gc1 = Inst("GenericClass", "I am generic")
  val gc2 = Inst("GenericClass", gc1)
  println(s"""\nthese objects have been instantiated:\n${List(c1,c2,cc,gc1,gc2).mkString("\n")}""")
}
```

Note that it requires this `build.sbt` or a similar one:

```
lazy val reflection = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value % "provided",
      "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value % "provided"
    )
  )
```