# Is it possible to find a common supertype on type-system level in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

Is it possible to make a type-alias (or something equivalent) in Scala that takes two parameters and returns their common supertype? In other words, I'm trying to find something with this signature:

```
type CommonSupertype[A, B] // can't be more specific
```

where these hold true: (pseudocode)

```
CommonSupertype[String, Int] = Any
CommonSupertype[JButton, JPanel] = JComponent
```

etc.

I haven't been able to find it myself, but I can't use alternatives like adding an extra parameter, since I have to follow a pre-specified interface.

Comment: Give us a use case with sample code so we can work something out.

Comment: This isn't possible via a type alias, but in context there are things you can do which have a similar effect ... so I echo @Jean-PhilippePellet in asking for a use case or two.

Comment: Yes: `type CommonSupertype[A, B] = Any`. But I think you might be looking for the **least** common supertype...

Comment: Two types don't necessarily have a least common supertype (think multiple traits). Or would that be a greatest common supertype?

Comment: The use case sample is complicated (many files), so I'll have to simplify it a bit. Working on it. @michid I meant least common supertype.

Comment: It's for some metaprogramming, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

(Not a complete solution, but might give some ideas)

One impressive feature of Scala is its ability to return a list of Fruits when an orange is appended to a list of apples.
It's fine with values, precisely because you let the generic type be inferred.

```
import scala.reflect.Manifest

def CommonSuperType[A, B >: A : Manifest](a:A, b:B) = manifest[B]
```

It works (kind of) :

```
scala> CommonSuperType(new JButton, new JPanel)
res42: Manifest[javax.swing.JComponent with javax.accessibility.Accessible] = javax.swing.JComponent with javax.accessibility.Accessible
```

Next step would be to lift this trick to higher kinded types (not tested).
An half baked solution consists in creating values from types (cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818996/abstract-types-type-parameters-in-scala)) :

```
class CommonSuper[A:Manifest, B:Manifest] {
   def make[T:Manifest] = manifest[T].erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
   val instanceA = make[A]
   val instanceB = make[B]
   def getType = CommonSuperType(instanceA, instanceB)
}
```

But I'm stuck in this unintuitive inconsistency :

```
scala> val test = new CommonSuper[JButton, JPanel]

scala> test.getType
res66: Manifest[Any] = Any

scala> CommonSuperType(test.instanceA, test.instanceB)
res67: Manifest[javax.swing.JComponent with javax.accessibility.Accessible] = javax.swing.JComponent with javax.accessibility.Accessible
```

Anyway, whereas I'm fond of this type of questions (questions about types), here it smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a trait `CommonSupertype[A, B]` and an implicit generator function, so you can just require an implicit instance of this trait wherever you need it, and it will contain the common supertype (as a dependent type).

This is not my idea, it's actually adapted ever so slightly from [this post by Miles Sabin](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/).

The only change I've made is that, while he is using `¬¬[C] <:< (A ∨ B)` as evidence that a type C is a subtype of either A or B, I've reversed the subtyping direction (so: `(A ∨ B) <:< ¬¬[C]`) to check that both A and B are subtypes of C.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Main extends App {
  type ¬[A] = A => Nothing
  type ∨[T, U] = ¬[¬[T] with ¬[U]]
  type ¬¬[A] = ¬[¬[A]]

  trait CommonSupertype[A, B] {
    type λ
    def tag: ClassTag[λ]
  }
  // The ClassTag is only so I can get ahold of the type's name at runtime
  implicit def commonSupertype[A, B, C : ClassTag](implicit C: (A ∨ B) <:< ¬¬[C]): CommonSupertype[A, B] { type λ = C } =
    new CommonSupertype[A, B] { type λ = C; def tag = implicitly[ClassTag[C]] }

  trait Pet
  class Dog extends Pet
  class Cat extends Pet
  def check[A, B](implicit x: CommonSupertype[A, B]) = {
    // This just prints the common type, but you could use the type (x.λ) directly
    println(x.tag.toString())
  }
  check[Dog, Cat]
  check[Dog, Double]
}
```

Gives us:

```
Main.Pet
Any
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain typeTag of least common supertype and then extract its type (see [How to capture T from TypeTag[T] or any other generic in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053319/how-to-capture-type-from-typetag-or-any-other-generic-in-scala))

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.util._

def t[A, B] = (null.asInstanceOf[A], null.asInstanceOf[B])
implicit class RichTuple[A: TypeTag](a: (A, A)) {def common = typeTag[A]}

implicit class RichT[T: TypeTag](a: T) {//just helper for working with typetags 
   def asInstanceOfT[U](t: TypeTag[U]) = a.asInstanceOf[U]
   def hasSameTypeWith[U](t: TypeTag[U]) = typeTag[T] == t
}
```

Usage

```
scala> t[String, String].common
res87: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String] = TypeTag[String]

scala> t[String, Int].common
res88: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Any] = TypeTag[Any]

scala> ("aa" : String).hasSameTypeWith(t[String, String].common)
res105: Boolean = true

scala> ("aa" : String).hasSameTypeWith(t[String, Int].common)
res106: Boolean = false

scala> ("aa" : String).asInstanceOfT(t[String, Int].common)
res109: Any = aa 

scala> ("aa" : String).asInstanceOfT(t[Int, Int].common)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

For isInstanceOf see [How to know if an object is an instance of a TypeTag's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628379/how-to-know-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-typetags-type)

The only restriction is that you can't obtain common supertype of type parameters - it will always be erased to Any.