# How to capture T from TypeTag[T] or any other generic in scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types

Found how to [obtain typeTag for least common supertype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052147/1809978). But how to capture typetag's generic into type alias to operate type itself?

Assuming `TypeTag[SomeType]`, where `SomeType` is a result of type inference which is known in compile time (like result of `t[MyClass1, MyClass2].common` from [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052147/1809978))

```
type T = ??? // should be SomeType
```

I need it to automatically obtain common supertype even if my class hierarchy will be changed during refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if typeTag's generic was not erased (enough for extracting common supertype of types, that are known at compilation time):

```
class TypeHolder { type T }
object TypeHolder {
  def apply[U](a: TypeTag[U]) = new TypeHolder{type T = U} 
}
```

Usage:

```
val typ = TypeHolder(typeTag[Int])
val k: typ.T = 5
val list = List[typ.T]()
trait A { def aaaa: typ.T } 
someObject.isInstanceOf[typ.T]
```

But you can't do it with type variable because it will be "erased" to Any