# Declaring types based on types of other values

Tags: scala, types

At the moment, I have the following Scala code using the Scala Graph library:

```
val g = Graph.from(nodes, edges)
            // nodes: List[Table]; edges: List[LkUnDiEdge[Table,String]]
            // inferred - g: Graph[Table, LkUnDiEdge]

...

def nodeTransformer(innerNode: Graph[Table, LkUnDiEdge]#NodeT) = {
    val node = innerNode.value
    Some( root,
          DotNodeStmt(node.name, style(node)) )
}
```

You may notice the parameter to `nodeTransformer` is an inner type of the type of `g`. Similar code repeats the concrete Graph type or some of its type parameters in other places in the codebase.

Type inference does not work in all places, and I'd like a way to express this type dependency without repeating the same explicit types throughout the code. As an example, the C++ `typeof` operator would allow me to rewrite the function as follows:

```
def nodeTransformer(innerNode: typeof(g)#NodeT) = {
    ...
}
```

What is the sane way to express such static type dependencies in Scala when type inference fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
def nodeTransformer(innerNode: g.NodeT) = {
    ...
}
```

In contrast with C++ `typeof`, you should pass innerNode exactly for `g`, but not any other `Graph` instance (even with same type): [What is meant by Scala's path-dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types)

P.S. To extract type from generic (without type member inside) - [How to capture T from TypeTag[T] or any other generic in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053319/how-to-capture-t-from-typetagt-or-any-other-generic-in-scala)

Comment: The problem is that `nodeTransformer` is passed as a parameter to a different method (specifically as `inodeTransformer` of [toDot](http://scala-graph.org/guides/dot.html)), and the type of that argument is required to be `Graph[Table,LkUnDiEdge]#NodeT => Option[...]`. `g.NodeT` is incompatible with that required type.

Comment: you could try `innerNode:Graph[g.N,g.E]#NodeT`; N and E are unreachable as type members, but you can capture them using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053319/how-to-capture-t-from-typetagt-or-any-other-generic-in-scala

Comment: Oddly enough [this code](http://pastebin.com/QX7LaAGc) works. I'm going to mark this answer as accepted.

It is somewhat of killing a bug with a cannon, though, so I'm holding out hope someone can point out a saner way to achieve the same effect in Scala.

Comment: agree. actually i'd prefer some built-in mechanizm for scala to capture generics, but didn't find any.