# Scala supertype of call-by-name and call-by-value

Tags: scala, types

I want below code to be type-checked.

```
val f: Int => String = x => "a"
val g: (=> Int) => String = x => "b"
def t(h: ???): String = h(42)
t(f)
t(g)
```

What should be put in "???"?
I have read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015322/is-it-possible-to-find-a-common-supertype-on-type-system-level-in-scala) and tried it.

```
t[Int => String, (=> Int) => String].common
res4s: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[=> Int with Int => String] = TypeTag[=> Int with Int => String]
```

So I put "=> Int with Int => String" in the ???, but t(g) does not type-check.
I have tried "(=> Int with Int) => String" but t(f) does not type-check.

So the question is,

1. What is the meaning of "=> Int with Int => String" and why t(g) does not type-check
2. What is the meaning of "(=> Int with Int) => String" and why t(f) does not type-check
3. What should be put in ???

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

First of all type `X => Y` i.e. `Function1[X,Y]` is contravariant on type parameter `X` so you should search least common subtype, not greatest common supertype of `X` and `=>X`

Second - unfortunately there is not such subtype. More over it's very hard to define anything except function using type `=>X`. Although it's known such definition desugars later to `Function0[X]` on typecheck level types `=>X` and `()=>X` are not equivalent.

Happily we could define complex relations between types for our needs using typeclasses.

As we could use `=>X` only in parameter types we could define such a thing:

```
case class ParamConvertible[X, Y, T](apply: ((Y => T) => X => T))
```

Which looks and works like some narrow version of contravariant functor

And provide two obvious implementations

```
implicit def idParamConvertible[X, T] = ParamConvertible((f: X => T) => (x: X) => f(x))

implicit def byNameParamConvertible[X, T] = ParamConvertible((f: (=> X) => T) => (x: X) => f(x))
```

Now we can generalize your `t` function as

```
def t[T](h: T => String)
        (implicit conv: ParamConvertible[Int, T, String]): String =
  conv.apply(h)(42)
```

At this point your

```
t(f)
t(g)
```

Should compile and run nicely

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you mentioned, what I need is common supertype of `Int => String` and `=> Int => String`, and the least one should be "`Int` and `=> Int`'s common subtype" => String. From the mentioned link's code, I get `Int => String` and `=> Int => String`'s least common supertype is `=> Int with Int => String`. Which also implies `Int` and `=> Int`'s common subtype is `=> Int with Int`. (I am not sure if `=> Int` can stand alone as a type, but if so)
Could you give me some more explanation about _Second - unfortunately there is not such subtype._?

Comment: Thanks for your nice working code.
However, what I needed was to type-check given code without changing implicitly or explicitly the given paramater `h`. If it is not possible as you mentioned, I want to be fully convinced.
Again, thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Int => String` and `(=> Int) => String` don't have useful common super type. `Int => String` is the type of a call-by-value function which takes an `Int` value as first parameter and returns a `String`.

In contrast to that `(=> Int) => String` is a call-by-name function which takes an expression of type `Int` as the first parameter. Every time you access the call-by-name parameter the expression is evaluated. Thus, it is effectively a zero argument function returning an `Int`.

What you can do is to convert the call-by-name function into a call-by-value function so that `t(h: Int => String): String` type checks also with `g`. You simply have to call `t(g(_))`.